# How to Generate a new GUID from a given GUID in C# or T-Sql?

Tags: c#, sql, guid, uniqueidentifier

I want to copy a sqlserver table rows and insert into this table self ,this table have this fields:

```
Id :uniqueidentifier
ParentId: uniqueidentifier
Name: varchar(50)
Sort: float
UserId: uniqueidentifier
```

Id and ParentId Existing relationships.

I came up with a solution:

```
Insert into table1 (Id, ParentId,Name,Sort)
Select dbo.gen(id,1) as id, dbo.gen(ParentId,1) as ParentId ,Name,Sort from table1 
where UserId='XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX'
```

the gen function is method that Generate a new GUID from a given GUID

follow is a C# description and we can using in CLR SQL Server User-Defined Function:

```
public Guid GenerateNewGuid(Guid from,int seed)
{
    return .....
}
```

please help me how can i implement this function?

if you have other solution about my situation ,please let me know

Regards.

Jim

Comment: You need to specify the algorithm that creates the new guid from the existing guid with usage of the seed, otherwise we can't answer your question.

Comment: @Daniel i think he is asking for the algo ! !

Comment: @V4Vendetta,yes ,i am asking for the algorithm.  :)

Comment: @V4Vendetta: ok... But there is none...

Comment: @All:Ok,if there is no way to implement the algorithm,iIs there a way to solve the problem that copy table rows?

Comment: @guaike:yes, in SQL , see my answer please

Answer (score 5):

A GUID is a (Globally unique identifier), it's not like a AutoId were you can just increment by 1.

A GUID is meant to be Unique period. [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier)

Answer (score 1):

You can generate a new GUID in SQL with [NEWID()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190348.aspx)

If you want some *concept* of "sequence" use [NEWSEQUENTIALID()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189786.aspx)

> NEWSEQUENTIALID is a wrapper over the Windows UuidCreateSequential function.

However, there is no "seed" feasture like RAND.

So your SQL becomes...

```
Select NEWID() ...
```

Comment: this can't solve my question,notice:i need to copy the relationship  of fields of data

Answer (score 0):

Just create a new one:

```
public Guid GenerateNewGuid()
{
    return Guid.NewGuid();
}
```

Guids are not ordered or something like that. There is no algorithm like `newGuid = oldGuid + 1`.